# Are not all processors created equal?

Tags: windows, multithreading, winapi, cpu

My laptop has 4 logical processors (two physical); logical CPUs 1 and 2 map to core 1, and logical CPUs 3 and 4 map to core 2 (verified with `GetLogicalProcessorInformation()`).

I ran a multithreaded matrix multiplication program on my computer with two threads. The first time, I used `SetProcessAffinityMask(hProcess, 0x5)` (which means logical processors 1 and 3) while the second time I used `SetProcessAffinityMask(hProcess, 0xA)` (logical processors 2 and 4).

It turned out that the first version was about twice as fast as the second version, as though I'd never multithreaded the second version anyway.

Does anyone have any guesses as to why this might be happening?

---

**Measurements:**

- Plugged in (full CPU):

  - Affinity mask: 0x3 (0011b), 9 gflop/s
  - Affinity mask: 0x5 (0101b), 17 gflop/s
  - Affinity mask: 0x6 (0110b), 17 gflop/s
  - Affinity mask: 0x9 (1001b), 9 gflop/s
  - Affinity mask: 0xA (1010b), 9 gflop/s
  - Affinity mask: 0xC (1100b), 9 gflop/s
- On battery (clocked down):

  - Affinity mask: 0x3 (0011b), 5 gflop/s
  - Affinity mask: 0x5 (0101b), 10 gflop/s
  - Affinity mask: 0x6 (0110b), 10 gflop/s
  - Affinity mask: 0x9 (1001b), 5 gflop/s
  - Affinity mask: 0xA (1010b), 2 gflop/s
    (--> Very interesting, why half speed when on battery but normal speed on AC?! this one varies a lot between 1.5-2.5 gflop/s, unlike the others.)
  - Affinity mask: 0xC (1100b), 5 gflop/s

*Does this imply that the fourth logical CPU is not doing anything (!)?* (Everything with the mask for the fourth CPU set is slow.)

---

**Update:**

I just ran the same thing on the High Performance profile *on batteries*. The results are inconsistent: This time, I got 2x speedup for the masks 5, 6, and 10, but there was no speedup for mask 12. I'll try to run the tests again on AC power, but ultimately it seems like this result is a combination of power management, Turbo Boost, scheduling inconsistencies, etc., and it's more difficult to measure than I previously thought. :(

Comment: Do you have hyperthreading enabled?

Comment: Maybe the system is using the CPU? i.e. something else has set SetProcessAffinityMask() before you. Did you check the processor usage before you started? How many times did you run the test? You should run then multiple times and take an average to minimise the interference of other apps/system jobs.

Comment: any other processes running? Run the tests many times to get better statistics

Comment: @Gabe: Not sure what you mean by "enabled" -- I definitely have 4 logical CPUs, if that's what you mean. There's no BIOS option for anything, and I doubt that anything is turned off.
@PAntoine, @Erno: No, the system is idle, and I ran this test quite a few times.

Comment: @Mehrdad: I've never seen a laptop with two physical CPUs. What kind is it?

Comment: @Gabe: By "CPU" I meant cores... should have made sense since I said CPUs 1 and 2 map to **core** 1.

Comment: So then you have a single dual-core CPU with hyperthreading. What kind of CPU is it?

Comment: Oh please do tell us the model number!

Comment: @Gabe, @David: Yes, single dual-core with hyperthreading, Intel Core i5 520M, 2.40 GHz, and 2.93 GHz (I *think*) with Turbo Boost.

Comment: Turbo Boost will have an effect. The more cores you have active, the slower your clockspeed will be. It shouldn't be a 2x difference, though.

Comment: @Gabe: But it's the same number of cores! That's why it's surprising me. And the boost was from 9 gflop/s to 17 gflop/s, almost a factor of 2.

Comment: @Mehrdad: If the OS is scheduling something on Core 1 and you execute something on Core 1, your CPU will run at 3Ghz. If the OS is scheduling something on Core 1 and you execute something on Core 2, your CPU will run at 2.4GHz.

Comment: @Gabe: But I can assure you my CPUs are all **99% idle** except for this program, there's nothing else running. And either way, that doesn't explain the speed difference...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be good to know what physical CPU this is, but I'm assuming from your phrasing about logical processors that there is 1 physical socket, 2 CPU cores, and hyperthreading is enabled giving you 4 logical processors.

The short answer is, for this complicated definition of "processor", no, not all processors are created equal. Hyperthreaded logical cores share execution resources, and if there's contention for those resources they won't be fast as separate physical cores. This sharing can take place at different levels for both hyperthreading and multicore processors (ALU, execution resources, cache at different levels, etc) but in broad terms, physical cores in the same socket won't be affected much by what the other core(s) is/are doing, and logical cores implemented by hyperthreading will be hugely affected by what their hypertwin is doing.

Another difference between different CPUs: As Ben said, your OS may process most hardware interrupts on a single CPU, which means that CPU will seem slower for other purposes, but I'd be surprised if the interrupt load is enough to impact performance anywhere near this much.

The results you got -- on processors A and B (being intentionally ambiguous about which 2 processors those are) you get double the performance of A alone, but on processors A and C you get approximately the same performance as A alone -- sure sound like hyperthreading is the difference, where A and C are hypertwins in the same physical core, and B is in the other physical core. You said that GetLogicalProcessorInformation() claims otherwise, but it's not unheard of for the BIOS tables on which that depends to have errors.

I would run Task Manager, keep an eye on loads on each CPU before you run your test to get an idea of how much else is going on and where Windows schedules it, then run your test again a few times, for different combinations of CPU affinity, and see if you can confirm or deny this theory.

Comment: @metamatt: Thanks for the explanation, but like I wrote under @Blank's comment, changing 0x5 to 0x9 didn't change anything. So that means running on logical processors A/B is twice as fast, but on A/C and A/D are **both** twice at slow. Hyperthreading does **not** explain this.

Comment: @metamatt: Oops sorry, typo: I meant changing **0xA** to **0x9** didn't change anything; 0x5 was the fast mask.

Comment: @Mehrdad, have you verified watching the per-cpu graphs in Task Manager that the threads are ending up scheduled as you'd expect for each test scenario? As Blank Xavier said, if you only set affinity at the process level and not per thread, Windows is free to schedule both threads on the same processor (either of the two that the process affinity mask allows). That would be perverse, but would explain what's going on, so let's rule it out if it's not happening.

Comment: But yes, wrt hyperthreading, of the 6 options you have for 2-out-of-4 affinity, if hyperthreading were the culprit you'd expect to see 2 slow results and 4 fast ones. You're seeing 2 fast and 4 slow, so hyperthreading does not appear to explain this.

Comment: @metamatt: See my update. Now I see 3 fast and 1 slow out of all combinations of processors from CPUs 1/2 and 3/4, so it seems like my tests are inconsistent. :( I'll accept your answer since I'm starting to get inconsistencies, and since you pointed out to watch the load on each CPU separately, since I observed something else that was also important: when clocked down, the OS distributes the thread loads across all four CPUs, whereas when at full clock speed, the OS maxes out only 2 logical CPUs. Thanks!

Comment: That sounds like Turbo Boost kicking in -- Core i5 can act like 1 fast core (with 2 logical processors) or 2 slower cores (with 4 logical processors). I don't have direct experience with Turbo Boost, but things were already confusing with hyperthreading and Turbo Boost makes things more so.

Answer (score 1):

SetProcessAffinityMask() does not guarantee you will have one thread per core; only that the threads you have will run on the cores you have allowed.

Perhaps the OS is scheduling differently.

Also, I'm surprised 1 and 2 are on core 1.  Usually, logical processor numbers interleave over physical cores, to provide an inherent load balancing.  I would expect 1 and 3 to be on core 1, 2 and 4 to be on core 2.

Comment: @Blank: Not sure what you mean by the first and second paragraphs, or how it explains the discrepancy. As for #3, I verified it, but in case it makes any difference, I tried passing in 9 instead of 5 and the result was the same.

Comment: Say you have a process with 10 threads.  You use SetProcessAffinityMask() to specify say six cores.  Those ten threads can run on any of those six cores.  Maybe the OS puts all ten threads on one core - it can; there's nothing to stop it doing so.  It might be doing so in one case for you, but not the other (unlikely, but possible).  If you want to pin a thread to a core, you need to specify the core during the call to CreateThread().

Comment: @Blank: Windows has thread affinity too, see SetThreadAffinityMask. You don't need to specify thread affinity when the thread is born.

Comment: @Mehrdad: yes.  You have two threads.  You have allowed to OS to run them on two cores.  The OS is free to run both threads on either CPU, or one on each.

Comment: @metamatt: my mistake - I was thinking of my own abstraction layer!  both Windows and Linux use a separate function call to indicate thread affinity.

Comment: Just a minor correction here - how logical cores are numbered actually depends upon the OS in use. For some, they are interleaved as @user82238 indicates, but for others, they are sequential. This varies between Windows releases IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

No, not all cores are equal.  Only one is the boot core.  Furthermore, in many cases all IRQs (or at least IRQs from a majority of the devices) are directed to a single core.

---

More important to your observed behavior, not all **sets** of cores are equal.  In a NUMA memory architecture (which have been relatively mainstream in x86 since Intel Hyperthreading and AMD Opteron), there's an ideal group of processors which can efficiently access a particular region of memory, and all other processors will pay a significant penalty to access that range.

With Hyperthreading, it's not main system memory that's connected non-uniformly, but L1 and L2 cache.  If your process migrates between the two virtual processors associated to the same physical core, the cache remains valid.  But if it migrates to the other physical core, cached data has to be copied and ownership transferred to the other cache.  For some workloads, this could make a big difference.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the "boot core"? If you mean "the core the computer is booted from", then okay, but that doesn't explain the discrepancy...

Comment: When a multi-CPU x86 system first boots, only one processor is active (the boot service processor, or BSP). At some point you'll start booting an OS, and the OS (running only on the BSP at this point) will go and enumerate and activate the other processor(s), which are called application processors, or APs. Depending on how the OS schedules things, the distinction between BSP and AP shouldn't matter for subsequent performance, though as Ben said some OSes use the BSP for handling all hardware interrupts, which of course leaves the BSP less time for doing other things.

Comment: @metamatt: Okay, but why would a mask of 5 be fast whereas a mask of 9 and 0xA would be slow? This does not explain the phenomenon at all...

Comment: @Mehrdad, my edit should explain that.  Also, both 0x9 and 0xA include (1 << 3), and so if that CPU was heavily loaded by interrupts, this behavior could arise.  But you said that 0x3 gives you the same results.

Comment: @Ben: So you're saying if I prevent dynamic migrations by using `SetThreadAffinityMask` to lock threads to a single processor, it should fix this? And again, I've mentioned that the CPU *is **not** loaded by interrupts*. And I can reproduce this every time with no exceptions. :P

Comment: @Mehrdad: Even then, there will be an effect on data shared between threads.  And interrupts are always occurring.  How are you measuring idleness?  It's possible to get 10% or more of a core used without ticking the Task Manager readout above 1%, because the core is idle every time sampling occurs.

Comment: @Ben: I know it's idle because I don't have any processes that are running, and because I explicitly use `SetPriorityClass` and `SetThreadPriority` to set both priorities to realtime. It can't get any more accurate than that, and I'm darn sure my measurements are valid.

Comment: @Ben: I don't get what you mean by "an effect on data shared between threads"... it's quite vague here, and doesn't say if it's a 5% difference or a 50% difference or a 500% difference.

Comment: +1 for the great info on NUMA and cache-related issues with hyperthreading.

Comment: @Mehrdad: What I mean is that data shared between threads is going to require ownership transfer between the caches, which is an order of magnitude more expensive than a cache hit.  How that affects overall performance depends on how much data your application shares and the exact access pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the return code from `SetProcessAffinityMask` to see if there was an error? If the call fails, you might get stuck on one logical processor. According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686223(v=vs.85).aspx), you can only use the bits that are set in the result of `GetProcessAffinityMask`.

You say you've tried masks of `0x5`, `0xA`, and `0x9`. I'd be curious to see the results with `0x3`.

Comment: The return value is 1 for all of them, and calling `GetProcessAffinityMask` returns the same mask I pass it. Furthermore, a mask of 0x3` is also 9 gflops (slow).

Comment: @Mehrdad, GetProcessAffinityMask will return two masks; you need to look at the System mask. It's a long shot I know, because I can't think of a reason why the system mask wouldn't be 0xf.

Comment: I just looked at the system mask and it's `0xF`. I can't think of why it wouldn't be either. :P